# CA taxes on invesment income for part time-resident

Tags: united-states, income-tax, california, state-income-tax, foreign-income

I lived outside of the US from July 2016 - November 22d of 2017. All my income from this period is investment income.

My understanding is that because it is investment income it does not qualify for any kind of federal exemption, like foreign earned income does.

What I have not been able to figure out yet is if I qualify for any kind of reduction on my CA state taxes. I have no income earned in the state of CA itself and during 2017 was only in CA from Nov 22 to Dec 31st (a total of 39 days).

I'm assuming that if I don't qualify as a non-resident I do at least qualify as a part-time resident? Can I claim this status and will it entitle me to any sort of tax reduction? Or does it make no difference for taxes on investment income?

Comment: What was the nexus of your investment income?  Was it investments in the US?  Were they investments in an overseas country?